# Having Methods with Multiple Strings

Tags: android, sql, cursor, spinner

I know this isn't correct because it doesn't work, but I am not sure why this does not work.

I have multiple spinners populated from a database by queries.

```
vTypeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int
                pos, long id) {
                 if(pos!=0){

                    Cursor vTypeChose = (Cursor)(vTypeSpinner.getSelectedItem());
                    if (vTypeChose != null) {
                        String typePicked = vTypeChose.getString(
                        vTypeChose.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.POWERSPORTS_TYPE));
                        vMake = (Cursor) DataBaseHelper.getPowersportsMake(typePicked);
                        scaMake.changeCursor(vMake);
                        Log.e("SpinnerTest", "Type Selected: " + vType.getString(vType.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.POWERSPORTS_TYPE)));


                    }
                 }
            }

    vMakeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int
                pos, long id) {
                 if(pos!=0){

                Cursor vMakeChose = (Cursor)(vMakeSpinner.getSelectedItem());
                if (vMakeChose != null) {
                    makePicked = vMakeChose.getString(
                    vMakeChose.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.POWERSPORTS_MAKE));
                    vYear = (Cursor) DataBaseHelper.getPowersportsYear(typePicked, makePicked);
                    scaYear.changeCursor(vYear);
                    Log.e("SpinnerTest", "Make Selected: " + vMake.getString(vMake.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.POWERSPORTS_MAKE)));


                }
             }
        }
```

Once the vMakeSpinner item is selected, it starts the vYearSpinner code

And this is my year spinner query

```
public static Cursor getPowersportsYear(String typePicked, String makePicked){
return myDataBase.query(POWERSPORTS_TABLE, 
        new String [] {POWERSPORTS_ID, POWERSPORTS_YEARS}, 
        POWERSPORTS_TYPE+"='"+typePicked+"'" +" AND " + POWERSPORTS_MAKE+"='"+makePicked+"'", 
        null, 
        POWERSPORTS_YEARS, 
        null, 
        null);
}
```

If I only have one string value within the DataBaseHelper methods, it works fine but only with one where argument.

Updated with some Code:

```
public class PowersportsEquivalent extends Activity {

DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;
String typePicked;
String makePicked;
String yearPicked;
SimpleCursorAdapter scaMake;
SimpleCursorAdapter scaYear;

Cursor vMake;
Cursor vYear;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_powersports_equivalent);
```

Comment: try using `POWERSPORTS_TYPE+"="+typePicked+" AND " + POWERSPORTS_MAKE+"="+makePicked`

Comment: App crashes with the supplied code. gives an LogCat error: `12-20 11:11:55.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3180): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "makeDemo2": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, powersports_years FROM powersports_data WHERE powersports_type=null AND powersports_make=makeDemo2  GROUP BY powersports_years`

Comment: `powersports_type=null` tells you that your `typePicked` is null please check or put a manual value there.

Comment: I can confirm that the value is null by assigning a variable manually  to the typePicked variable. vYearSpinner populates. How am I passing a null for typePicked when the 2nd spinner is populated from the variable typePicked?

Comment: use a toast or log to check whether typePicked is actually having a value or not.

Comment: are you sure you are initializing your typePicked? Because i can't see it in the above code? Is your typePicked global?

Comment: I updated my original post with some code showing that the variable is outside my onCreate, so that makes it global correct?

Comment: you error log does not match your code. also, you cursor query is inconsistent with your getColumnIndex calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that I needed to get the string value again in my cursors. So I added:

```
typePicked = vType.getString(
                vType.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.POWERSPORTS_TYPE));
```

in my make cursor, and my spinners work now.

Answer (score 0):

you have used

```
String typePicked = vTypeChose.getString(
                        vTypeChose.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.POWERSPORTS_TYPE));
```

in `vTypeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener()` which makes typePicked as local variable. I think you have no where initialized the **global typePicked**. Remove **String** in the code above and then you code should work properly.